# django 1.4.3 file structure?how to access the images?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-models

i am using django 1.4.3 version and i am not able set the media path so that i can access my images.i have searched in the Google but nothing is helped me to solve this. My project structure is like below

1. indianstartup

   - indianapp

     - admin.py
     - models.py
     - views.py
     - templates/

       - index.html
       - h.html
     - media/

       - abc.jpg
   - indianstartup

     - settings.py
     - urls.py

**now in models.py i am using imagefield like below**

```
pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="media/")
```

the above one is not working, how can i save or upload a image to my media folder which is in "indianapp" folder and how can i show the  same image in the html file?

**Settings file**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**added view.py**

**views.py**

```
def singlepost(request, year, month, slug2):
posts, pagedata = init() 
img=posts.get
post = posts.get(date_created__year=year,
                        date_created__month=int(month),
                        slug=slug2,)
pagedata.update({'post': post})
return render_to_response('singlepost.html', pagedata)
```

so iam trying to get the image by post.pic in like

```
<img src="{{post.pic}}">
```

but not working

Comment: try pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="/media/")

Comment: already tried but didn't worked

Comment: As I see, your MEDIA_ROOT point to indianstartup/media, check it.

Comment: So it means your media root is not correct 
so try change your media_root like '/home/media'(full path where your media folder exist)
and then MEDIA_URL = 'media'

Comment: yeah it is saving the images in indianstartup/media folder.Really thank you for this.how can i show the image in html <img src> tag?

Comment: Keep in mind that upload_to option tells Django to which *subdirectory of MEDIA_ROOT* it should upload files.